# I got some errors when i start a tomcat server in idea, i don't know how to resolve it.It's the log information below

Tags: java, tomcat

Firstly, i created a javeEE module in a project in idea, and i could started the server normally, i wrote code as usual, After a while, when i started the tomcat server again, i got some error information.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thank U very much!!!

The code I wrote before the problem went wrong.

**File1**:This file was used to test the getContextPath() method.

```java
//file1
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/responseDemo1")
public class ResponseDemo1 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("demo1...");

        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        response.sendRedirect(contextPath+"/responseDemo2");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doPost(request, response);
    }
}
```

**File2:**

```java
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/responseDemo2")
public class ResponseDemo2 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("responsedemo2...");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doPost(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is the ful Server Startup Log.

```
D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin\catalina.bat run
[2020-05-22 01:12:04,081] Artifact day15_response:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\_JavaWeb"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
22-May-2020 13:12:06.223 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server.服务器版本: Apache Tomcat/9.0.35
22-May-2020 13:12:06.229 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 服务器构建:        May 5 2020 20:36:20 UTC
22-May-2020 13:12:06.229 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 服务器版本号(:     9.0.35.0
22-May-2020 13:12:06.229 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 操作系统名称:      Windows 10
22-May-2020 13:12:06.230 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS.版本:           10.0
22-May-2020 13:12:06.230 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 架构:              amd64
22-May-2020 13:12:06.230 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java 环境变量:     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6
22-May-2020 13:12:06.230 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java虚拟机版本:    11.0.6+8-LTS
22-May-2020 13:12:06.230 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM.供应商:        Oracle Corporation
22-May-2020 13:12:06.230 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\_JavaWeb
22-May-2020 13:12:06.231 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:     D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35
22-May-2020 13:12:06.233 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
22-May-2020 13:12:06.233 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
22-May-2020 13:12:06.233 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
22-May-2020 13:12:06.234 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\_JavaWeb\conf\logging.properties
22-May-2020 13:12:06.234 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-May-2020 13:12:06.234 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10991
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\_JavaWeb\jmxremote.password
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\_JavaWeb\jmxremote.access
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
22-May-2020 13:12:06.235 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
22-May-2020 13:12:06.237 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
22-May-2020 13:12:06.237 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\_JavaWeb
22-May-2020 13:12:06.238 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Dcatalina.home=D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35
22-May-2020 13:12:14.513 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 命令行参数：-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\temp
22-May-2020 13:12:14.517 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent 使用APR版本[1.7.0]加载了基于APR的Apache Tomcat本机库[1.2.24]。
22-May-2020 13:12:14.518 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR功能：IPv6[true]、sendfile[true]、accept filters[false]、random[true]。
22-May-2020 13:12:14.518 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL配置：useAprConnector[false]，useOpenSSL[true]
22-May-2020 13:12:14.640 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL成功初始化 [OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020]
22-May-2020 13:12:15.119 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init 初始化协议处理器 ["http-nio-8080"]
22-May-2020 13:12:15.186 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load 服务器在[9,493]毫秒内初始化
22-May-2020 13:12:15.311 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal 正在启动服务[Catalina]
22-May-2020 13:12:15.311 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal 正在启动 Servlet 引擎：[Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
22-May-2020 13:12:15.338 信息 [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start 开始协议处理句柄["http-nio-8080"]
22-May-2020 13:12:15.361 信息 [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start [174]毫秒后服务器启动
Connected to server
[2020-05-22 01:12:15,806] Artifact day15_response:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
22-May-2020 13:12:16.469 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke 调用方法[manageApp]时发生异常
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 启动子级时出错
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 无法启动组件[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/day15]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: servlet映射中的<url pattern>[response/Demo4]无效
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3183)
        at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1168)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5052)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 more
22-May-2020 13:12:16.478 严重 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke 调用方法[createStandardContext]时发生异常
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: 调用方法[manageApp]时发生异常
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 启动子级时出错
[2020-05-22 01:12:16,519] Artifact day15_response:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 无法启动组件[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/day15]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: servlet映射中的<url pattern>[response/Demo4]无效
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3183)
        at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1394)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1168)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5052)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 43 more
22-May-2020 13:12:25.376 信息 [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\webapps\manager]
22-May-2020 13:12:26.418 警告 [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom 使用[SHA1PRNG]创建会话ID生成的SecureRandom实例花费了[511]毫秒。
22-May-2020 13:12:26.520 信息 [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Web应用程序目录[D:\xxx\xxx\apache-tomcat-9.0.35-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\webapps\manager]的部署已在[1,144]毫秒内完成
```

Comment: If this is not for a school assignment, the way to resolve it is generally to use a modern framework like Spring Boot or Micronaut that handles all of the server details for you so that you can use your attention on your business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons you are getting this error .For further analysis please share entire stacktrace . Some of the reasons that you are seeing this error during artifact deployment maybe because :

- You are missing a related dependency in your artifact which is causing the artifact startup to fail. In such a scenario go through the entire log to find out of the startup logged(check tomcat logs) any dependency as missing.Add it to build to resolve issue
- Check that any connections that you are trying to make from this application is reachable. Since I saw RMI in the log it might be because the connection could not be made which is failing your application.
- You are having conflicts in your dependency which prevents application startup.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, i deleted that module(the module has only a small amount of code) , then i Re-create the previous module and rewrite the corresponding code. Fortunately, this time the tomcat server started normally.